Building in x64 with generator Visual Studio 17 2022
I want to make an x64 build of my project, but no matter what I do, CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM sets to Win32 in the CMakeCache file whenever I set the generator to "Visual Studio 17 2022".
I've included set(CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM x64) in my cmakelist file to no avail. I tried setting the generator to "Visual Studio 17 2022 win64" but then I get an error that says that it can't find the compiler. I've deleted the cache and recompiled probably about a million times. I've checked that I have all the necessary VS extensions, and tried "repairing" visual studio.

You should be using the -A switch:
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64

